# Miracast over Infrastructure not working

Tags: windows-10, miracast

I have a notebook and I have a tablet PC.
Both running Windows 10 x64 1803 (PC runs PRO, tablet runs Home).
Both are connected the same network: notebook is connected via Ethernet cable and tablet PC is connected via Wi-Fi.

I'd like to make tablet PC to act as a second screen using built-in Windows tools.
When I enable Wi-Fi on both notebook and tablet PC, then open Connect app on my tablet PC, my notebook easily finds second screen (Win+P > Connect to a wireless display) and everything works as needed. So, Miracast over Wi-Fi (MoW) working

I Googled a little and found that Windows 1703+ has an ability to use 'Miracast over infrastructure': connecting external display using existing connections, not direct Wi-Fi connection. It is called 'Miracast over infrastructure' (MoI) and it is documented in 'MS-MICE' protocol.

On Microsoft site it is told that MoI is supposed to be working exactly the same way MoW works: end user does not have to know how receiver is connected.

But in my case, I can not find any displays this way.

```
Tablet PC is connected over Wi-Fi. The connection is marked as 'Private'. IPv6 is disabled on interface. It has IP 172.19.21.108 (172.19.21.0/24 is my internal home network). Firewall is disabled
Notebook is connected over Ethernet. The connection is marked as 'Private'. IPv6 is disabled on interface. It has IP 172.19.21.105
```

The notebook PC **can** find tablet PC over mDNS and ping it:
ping CHUWI-TAB

I don't even know where to start diagnostics. Could you help me?

Comment: Miracast requires very specific hardware.  Does your hardware meet the requirements for Miracast?  Windows 10 supporting Miracast is only 1/2 of the equation.

Comment: Miracast over wifi (direct) is working. Do I need any special hardware (e.g. ethernet card) for miracast over infrastructure?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to turn your tablet into a second screen for your notebook, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right. And it works perfectly over classic miracast (over direct ad-hoc wi-fi). But it does not work using 'Miracast over Infrastricture'

Comment: Your access point is configured to use `WPA2-PSK` or `WPA2-Enterprise`?

Comment: WPA2-PSK. It' just a SoHo Netgear router.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82325/discussion-between-ramhound-and-filimonic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you keep wifi turned on for both machines,  Miracast over infrastructure still uses a direct p2p wifi connection for initial discovery, but then uses your existing infrastructure. can check it is using your wired network in task manager. open a video on the miracast display and  you will see high usage for your Ethernet adaptor if MOI is working.

Microsoft documentation has been updated https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/surface-hub/miracast-over-infrastructure

Comment: Do you have a reference to back up this answer?

Comment: Quote original MS site: 

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/surface-hub/miracast-over-infrastructure

Why do I still need Wi-Fi to use Miracast over infrastructure?
Discovery requests to identify Miracast receivers can only occur through the Wi-Fi adapter. Once the receivers have been identified, Windows 10 can then attempt the connection to the network.

Answer (score 1):

Sad to see the downvotes on a correct answer from bung. Since my rep is too low I cannot add a comment to back up bung's answer so I'll provide my own.

The answer is that you still need an active Wireless-adapter to establish the Miracast session. After the discovery-process is completed the stream will use lan/ethernet/infrastructure.

Probably since this question was posted (and downvotes given to answers), [the Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/surface-hub/miracast-over-infrastructure) has been updated with the following information:

> On Windows 10 PCs, the **Projecting to this PC** feature must be enabled in System Settings, and the device must have a Wi-Fi interface enabled in order to respond to discovery requests that only occur through the Wi-Fi adapter.

Along with an FAQ-section that reads:

> **Why do I still need Wi-Fi to use Miracast over infrastructure?**
>
> Discovery requests to identify Miracast receivers can only occur
> through the Wi-Fi adapter. Once the receivers have been identified,
> Windows 10 can then attempt the connection to the network.

Answer (score 0):

Miracast over Infrastructure requires a few things to get it working. I am still working through this myself in our organization. (We are crossing vlans,  which complicates things a bit for us)

Basically, the main requirements are:

1. Be on the same network, or something that can forward the mdns requests
2. A windows source must have a firewall rule for %systemroot%\System32\WUDFHost.exe allowing the ports required for miracast inbound. (The sink initiates a connection back to the source once connected)
3. The sink (receiver) must be resolvable by DNS. From what I can tell this is only required if the device does not provide an IP Address with its mdns beacons/responses.
4. If on a domain, your Wireless Policy GPO must allow wifi direct groups, and allow everyone to create all user profiles.
5. The sink and receiver must both be connected via secure a connection - WPA2-PSK or WPA2-Enterprise, or via ethernet. (A wireless adapter is still required when using ethernet)